# DatePicker not incrementing the bound value in .Net Maui

Tags: c#, maui

I'm learning .net Maui by building out a small application.  And am at the last few details in the app, it's been a fun experience.

I've got a QueryProperty being imported into a ViewModel:

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(Customer), nameof(Customer))]

public partial class CustomerDetailViewModel : ObservableObject
{
     ...
```

Which matches the Observable property:

```
[ObservableProperty]
CustomerLicensesReturn Customer;
```

In the XAML I have a DatePicker:

```
<DatePicker Date="{Binding Customer.validUntil}"/>
<Button Text="Add Year" Margin="10" Command="{Binding AddYearCommand}"/>
```

The value is set right on class instantiation.

The above button is clicked and I intend on advancing the date 1 year.

```
[RelayCommand]
void AddYear()
{
    Customer.validUntil = Customer.validUntil.Value.AddMonths(12);
}
```

This is the DataModel:

```
namespace DataModels
{
    public class CustomerLicensesReturn : ObservableObject
    {
        public int? licenseID { get; set; }
        public int? CustomerID { get; set; }
        public DateTime? validUntil { get; set; }
        public string? ApplicationName { get; set; }
        public bool? IsValid { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This RelayCommand is hit, and the Customer.validUntil does increment, but the value is not reflected in the XAML DatePicker control.  I can click on it numerous times and watch the Customer.validUntil increment a year each time.

I assume it's due to the binding of the control in XAML, but I don't see any other way to bind the data to the control.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: please show the code for `validUntil`

Comment: There is no additional code other than the [RelayCommand] AddYear() above

Comment: How is it defined?  What type is it?  Is it an ObservableProperty?  If the problem is that changes to `validUntil` are not shown in the UI, then seeing all of that is highly relevant.

Comment: Its defined as I have in the code above...  It's all there...

Comment: Unless you mean the dataobject. There's no code with that, but it's a simple date time.  I can update with that object.

Comment: You either need to use ObservableObject or INotifyPropertyChanged if you want your UI to dynamically update when your model is changed

Comment: `Customer` has an `ObservableProperty` attribute, but that only works for the object itself, it does not apply to properties of that object

Comment: Makes sense, I did already have the MV inheriting ObservableObject and I added the ObservableObject to the data model.  It's still doing the same thing. (Update question with additional info)

Comment: you have to do more than just add the attribute.  You still need to use `SetProperty` .  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject